# JAXB inheritance - non-abstract base class

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

I'm currently trying to use JaxB but i'm not being very successful with a relatively simple example. My example is the following:

```
public class A {
   private String m_name;
}

public abstract class B_Base extends A {

}

public class B1 extends B_Base {
   private String m_value1;
}

public class B2 extends B_Base {
   private String m_value2;
}
```

All my attempts on (even marshalling) have failed. I have looked through Blaise Doughan's blog including articles such as http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html but none of them seem to help on my example. It is certainly possible that i've misapplied his examples. I would seem to me that my example should be something that is easily supported in JaxB - after all, java is largely based on inheritance relationships!

I would be grateful for a fast response!

Comment: Where is the jaxb annotations for the above classes and can you also add the example code for how you marshal/unmarshalled the classes mentioned in the question?

Comment: I've tried a humongous number of different arrangements of annotations and I didn't want to bore people with all the various attempts. However, I could put one example if you so wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

- JAXB will pull in super classes, but not subclasses.  You can create the `JAXBContext` on the leaf classes or you can use an `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation on the parent class to pull in the sub classes.
- You will need to provide root element information.  Below I have done this with a `JAXBElement`.

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(B1.class, B2.class);

        B1 b1 = new B1();
        JAXBElement<A> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<A>(new QName("root"), A.class, b1);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="b1"/>
```

---

## UPDATE

> hi, probably a really stupid question, but just wondering, how would I
>   adapt this if I have a class C that holds an ArrayList of A objects
>   (or subclasses)?

### Java Model

**C**

Here is the `C` class as described in your comment:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class C {

    private List<A> as = new ArrayList<A>();

    @XmlElement(name="a")
    public List<A> getAs() {
        return as;
    }

}
```

**A**

Here is how you can leverage the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation to bring in the subclasses.

```
@XmlSeeAlso({ B1.class, B2.class })
public class A {
    private String m_name;
}
```

### Demo Code

Below is some demo code to show everything works.  Note now that we use `@XmlSeeAlso` we use `@XmlSeeAlso` we don't need to include the subclasses when bootstrapping `JAXBContext`.

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(C.class);

        C root = new C();
        root.getAs().add(new B1());
        root.getAs().add(new B2());

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<c>
    <a xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="b1"/>
    <a xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="b2"/>
</c>
```

Comment: hi, probably a really stupid question, but just wondering, how would I  adapt this if I have a class C that holds an ArrayList of A objects (or subclasses)?

Comment: thanks very much for your efforts!! I will give this a go in the morning!